# Convert C# Type to the type of an array of type

Tags: c#, arrays, types

I need the Type of an Array of n elements of a type given in a Type variable.
I'm getting round the problem like this:

```
Type foo;
int n;

Type newType=(Array.CreateInstance(foo,n)).GetType();
```

This works but it does mean I'm actually creating an unused array just to get it's type. I'm sure there must be a better way!

Comment: Are you sure you need to get the "item type" as a `Type` instance? Maybe you could use a generic class instead, and then just do `TFoo[]`? This is just a thought, it entirely depends on how your entire type system is built :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Type.MakeArrayType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makearraytype):

```
Type foo = typeof(Foo);
Type arrayType = foo.MakeArrayType();
```

This returns the `Type` of an one-dimensional array of `Foo`. The `length` of the array is not relevant for the type.

For multi-dimensional arrays you can use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makearraytype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_MakeArrayType_System_Int32_)

```
Type foo = typeof(Foo);
int dimensions = 5;
Type arrayType = foo.MakeArrayType(dimensions);
```

Comment: foo.MakeArrayType() is exactly what I needed. Thanks.